# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

Tengo el siguiente código en un servicio y me lanza el siguiente error por consola:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'name'
>   of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Al parecer no esta reconociendo ninguno de los parametros

Si alguien tiene alguna idea! Gracias de Antemano!

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { GLOBAL } from './global';

@Injectable()
export class UploadService{
 public url: string;

 constructor(){
 this.url = GLOBAL.url;
 }
//al parecer no reconoce estos parametros
 makeFileRequest(url: string, params: Array<string>, files: Array<File>, token: string, name: string){

 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
 var formData: any = new FormData();
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   // El for dice que no reconoce el namespace Files
 for(var i = 0; < files.length; i++){

  formData.append(name, files[i], files[i].name);

 }

 xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){

 if(xhr.readyState == 4){

 if(xhr.status == 200){

  resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));

 }else{
  reject(xhr.response);

 }
 }
 }

 xhr.open('POST', url, true);
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Authotization', token);
 xhr.send(formData);

 });

 }
}
```

Desde aquí llamo al método del servicio

```js
this._uploadService.makeFileRequest(this.url+'upload-image-user/'+this.user._id, [], this.filesToUpload, this.token, 'image')
                           .then((result: any) => {
                              console.log(result);
                              this.user.image = result.image;
                              localStorage.setItem('identity', JSON.stringify(this.user));
                           });
      }
```

Comment: comprueba donde llamas al método `makeFileRequest()` del servicio si le estas pasando un valor para el parámetro `name`

Comment: El error te lo da cuando llamas a `makeFileRequest()` sin ningún fichero? Estaría bien que pudieras añadir cómo lo estás llamando.

Comment: He agregado mas arriba como lo estoy llamando, si le paso los valores de donde lo llamo

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `console.log(files);` antes del `for`?

Comment: **Soy nuevo en StackOverflow español y no puedo hacer comentarios, editaré esta respuesta, cuando encontremos la solución** files[i] no tiene la propiedad nombre, podrías mostrar cómo estás declarando esta variable donde consumes el servicio?

Comment: lo he puesto mas arriba es una variable de tipo string y tiene como valor 'image'

Comment: this.filesToUpload esta variable debe ser un array en el cual sus objetos tengan la propiedad "name", si no, no te va a encontrar este atributo.

Podrías poner el lugar donde estás asignándole valores a la variable?

Comment: public filesToUpload: Array<File>;  si es un Array

Comment: [object FileList] muestra esto

Comment: ¿Eso lo muestra el `console.log` o un `alert`?  ¿Y qué mostraría un `console.log(files[i]);` esta vez dentro del bucle `for`? Hay que depurar/ver lo que hay dentro de `files`...

Comment: Y la variable `this.filesToUpload` qué es? el `<input type="text">`?

Comment: Sí, pero el error te dice, que no hay nada en files[i].name, es decir que en ese array en la posición i, no hay un "name"  que se haya definido. En qué momento le asignas valores a ese array, para enviarlo como parámetro?

Comment: el objeto files se obtiene del DOM directo, no puedes obtenerlo via src o cosas asi con angular.

Comment: deberías fijarte si `this.filesToUpload` tiene algo antes de ejecutar `this._uploadService.makeFileRequest`. No sé donde se hará la llamada a makeFileRequest, pero puedes probar poneindo un `debugger` antes y llamar this.filesToUpload a ver que contiene

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'name'
>   of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

ahí te dice clarito el error, "no se puede leer propiedad 'name' de indefinido" y en el único lugar donde usas la propiedad name es en esta línea:

```
formData.append(name, files[i], files[i].name);
```

lo que significa que `files[i]` es igual a `undefined`

busca la forma de debugear tu código y lo comprobarás

Comment: estoy intentando

Comment: ahí te dieron algunos tips como `console.log(files[i])` tambien puedes usar los debugger que tienen los los navegadores usualmente apretando **ctrl + F12**

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con un foreach así:

```
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
files.forEach(file => {
  formData.append('fileItem[]', file, file.name);
});
```

En lugar de fileItem puede ir el nombre que tu quieras o la variable.

Comment: lo he intentado asi y sigue dando error me envia que TypeError: files.forEach is not a function

Comment: Pero entonces el problema viene de lo que le envias a la función, como le estas pasando el parametro files? Tu variable files tiene un valor undefined

Comment: Creo que el problema es más bien en como estas llenando tu array de files

Comment: esta en el codigo

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a modificar el código de dentro de la promesa así:

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById("myfileinput");
var files = fileInput.files; // Esta línea es la que no tienes
var file;

// loop through files
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  // get item
  file = files.item(i);
  // or
  file = files[i];

  console.log('File to upload: ', file.name);
```

}

Es decir, creo que lo que te hace falta es añadir a los ficheros:

`var files = fileInput.files;`

Comment: Lo he intentado y nada

Comment: ¿Podrías subir ese fragmento del código a un stackblitz para reproducirlo?